# Unable to debug web application using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I've followed closely several tutorials, but I can't get started with the simplest app. This is what I have so far.

I started a Dynamic Web app with Eclipse and made it a Maven project.

This is the project structure:

[image]

My Maven pom is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>HappySchedulerSpring</groupId>
  <artifactId>HappySchedulerSpring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Application.java and TweetsController.java are also very basic (just straight out of Spring example

```java
package com.pistacchioso.happyscheduler;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the Controller:

```java
package com.pistacchioso.happyscheduler;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TweetsController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "HappyScheduler";
    }

}
```

Nothing special in the .jsp file as well:

```jsp
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the debug icon, Eclipse makes me select Tomcat 8, no error is given, the dependencies are resolved correctly and the server is started, but `http:localhost:8080/greeting` keeps giving me 404.

Any help?

Comment: can you double check the port number?

Comment: The port number is correct. In fact, it is Tomcat that gives me a 404

Comment: Maybe the url is missspelled? Can you show us the last lines in the console?

Comment: i guess HappyScheduler.jsp need to be placed in src/main/resources/templates folder..

Answer (score 0):

First thing that catches my eye is @EnableAutoConfiguration in the controller. This annotation is intended to be put on configuration class, in your case Application.

However you don't need it since you are using @SpringBootApplication. It is a convenience annotation that assumes several things including auto configuration.

Try removing the @EnableAutoConfiguration from the controller.

Additionally, you can find an example similar to yours [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Answer (score 0):

First spring boot has inbuilt embedded tomcat, so we can package it as a jar and run the jar directly with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

or using java

```
java -jar target/SpringBootApplication.jar
```

As we are packaging with the jar file, WebApp folder will be ignored. So the html file need to be placed in src/main/resources/templates folder.

I have implemented in my local desktop and got the result

[image]

pom file for you reference - http://txs.io/jw6b